# Error Gcc.exe when trying install "Tools" for python 2.7.11

Tags: python, pip, mingw

I get error text:

```
Collecting scipy
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/84/a9/2bf119f3f9cff1f376f924e39cfae18dec92a1514784046d185731301281/scipy-1.10.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
      File "c:\users\vlkhr\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-ep5qs7\scipy\setup.py", line 27, in <module>
        from tools.version_utils import write_version_py, get_version_info
    ImportError: No module named tools.version_utils
    
    ----------------------------------------

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\vlkhr\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-ep5qs7\scipy
```

Help please!

Windows 11, GCC 4.3.3

I am trying to run my python 2.7 script.

First error : ImportError: No module named scipy

I'm trying to pip install scipy. I get "ImportError: No module named tools.version_utils"

I'm trying to pip install tools. I get command "'c:\mingw\bin\gcc.exe' failed with exit status 1."

Answer (score 0):

This is an incompatability with python 2.7, where directories needed to have an `__init__.py` file to be marked as importable python modules.

I would try with a `scipy` version that was python2.7 compatible. The latest one to have python 2.7. whls seems to be 1.2.3, so try

```
pip install scipy==1.2.3
```